# Unassigned hotkeys in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I search every hotkey possibilities in excel which unassigned. I want 2 macro 2 different ways but I don't know which hotkey is unassigned.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that help? There are linked workbooks that might help you.
[Shortcut Keys In Excel And VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShortCuts.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, that help for me. Thank you!